# Creating form boxes with labels

Tags: boxes, labels, forms

I want to recreate a form with LaTeX, that can be filled by hand or --- of course --- via LaTeX. How can I create the boxes, with a footnotesized label at the top and enough space for the text to be filled?

[image: form box]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to use the `mdframed` package:

[image]

### Notes:

- If you are just using a printed form you can use the `MyForm` macro.  But, if you desire the form to be electronically fill-able you can use the `\MyFormX` macro (as per Marco Daniel's suggestion).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% Use this if you want it electronically editable PDF.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\MyFormX}[2][1.0cm]{% 
    \begin{mdframed}[style=MyFormStyle]% 
    {\noindent\footnotesize#2}\\% 
    \TextField[format={var f =f.textFont = 'Verdana';f.strokeColor     =['T'];f.fillColor=['T']}, width=\linewidth, height=#1, charsize=10pt]{ }% 
    \end{mdframed}% 
}

\mdfdefinestyle{MyFormStyle}{%
    linewidth=1.5pt,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    skipabove=\topskip
}

\newcommand{\MyForm}[2][1.0cm]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=MyFormStyle]%
    {\noindent\footnotesize#2}\vspace{#1}%
    \end{mdframed}%
}


\begin{document}
Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before.
Text before. Text before. Text before. Text before.
Text before. Text before. Text before. 

\MyFormX{This one is electronically fill-able}

\MyForm[2.0cm]{Larger Space}

Text after Text After Text after Text After Text after
Text After Text after Text After Text after Text After
Text after Text After Text after 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `hyperref`: `\newcommand{\MyForm}[2][1.0cm]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=MyFormStyle]%
    {\noindent\footnotesize#2}\\%
     \TextField[format={var f =f.textFont = 'Verdana';f.strokeColor =['T'];f.fillColor=['T']},width=\linewidth,height=#1,charsize=10pt]{ }%
    \end{mdframed}%
}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I had interpreted "by hand" as in print format, but will update solution to also provide an electronically fill-able form if needed.