# Fillable form with text _inside_ the box, like in StackOverflow Title field

Tags: hyperref, forms

In the example below, the top box is generated with `hyperrf`, while the lower ones are generated with `tabular`. I want all boxes to be fillable (like the top one), but to look like the lower ones.

In more detail. This is a fillable form, that can either be printed and filled by a pen, or filled electronically, saved and later printed. To those ends, I find it necessary that:

- Field labels are in extremely small print and inside the fields. Thus when filled with pen, they will be written over and not visible any more.
- Similarly, if being filled electronically, the field labels should be able to be covered by the typed text.
- This is just a sample arrangement of the boxes(as in don't try hard to replicate it). The final document looks like [this](https://github.com/MiroslavVitkov/rpg/blob/master/build/charsheet.pdf).

How do I put the field label inside the field and possibly hide it if anything has been typed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}     % For coloured rows within tables.
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Hide section and page numbers.
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\TextField[bordercolor=black, width=8cm, height=5cm, charsize=0pt,name=box]{\tiny Външен вид}  \\
\end{Form}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\extrarowsep=1cm
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|}
\hline
{\tiny Сила}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

% Ловкост
\extrarowsep=1cm
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|}
\hline
{\tiny Ловкост}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\extrarowsep=4cm
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|}
\hline
{\tiny Рани}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This question seems related, and has an answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111079/17868